# identification of lego set by color and shape of inner box

Tags: set-identification

I'm trying to identify a lego set only knowing the color, shape of in inner package. The inner box is blue, dimensions are 18 x 11 x 2 3/8" and 9T plastic compartments,
There is a 1984 Lego Catalog included.  Tried to include a picture but don't know how to do it here.

Comment: Adding good pictures and changing the title of your question (to be more specific) will greatly improve the chances your set is identified.

Comment: George, since you can't add pictures yourself yet, could you add a link to a pic so that we can edit it in? Also, it's likely the catalogue isn't a full one and shows mostly sets of the same theme as the box, which woudl help, so if you can tell us more about it would be great.

Comment: For the inches-impaired ones about us, the dimensions in centimeters are more or less 45,75 x 28 x 6

Answer (score 2):

The only 1984 set with corresponding dimensions seems to be [6080 King's Castle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6080-1) but I can't find any picture of a possible inner tray; and that's even assuming it had one (the box picture on [this classic-castle forum post](http://www.classic-castle.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13083) seems to point to the contrary).

There's another good candidate in 1985: [6392 Airport](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6392-1), but again I can't find any pictures of the box.

1983 brings us [6980 Galaxy Commander](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=6980-1) for which I can't find pictures of the inner tray either (but there's [one on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lego-GALAXY-COMMANDER-6980-Set-w-Box-Classic-Space-5-minifigs-minifigures-1980s-/181210892127) where the seller promises pictures in the near future); [7824 Railway Station](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7824-1) is close too but it's a bit too short I had it and I don't remember it having a blue tray (I'm fairly confident it was red).

Answer (score 1):

Sets containing at least [100 pieces made in 1983 or 1984](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/setsearch?Inv=ANY&Inst=ANY&Thumbs=NO&ID=&Name=&Theme=&YearS=1983&YearE=1984&PcsS=100&PcsE=&FigsS=&FigsE=&MSRPS=&MSRPE=) would be my guess as to where to start searching...

Comment: Definitely a good start, but I'm a bit dubious as to why a 1983 set would contain a 1984 catalogue though.